# How do I blacklist HTML elements with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the code I'm running:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://mangapark.net/manga/tensei-shitara-slime-datta-ken-fuse'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('section', class_='manga')

manga_title = soup.find('div', class_='pb-1 mb-2 line-b-f hd')

for m_title in manga_title:
    title = m_title.find('a')
    if title != -1:
        print(f'Title: {title.text}')

manga_details = soup.find('table', class_='attr')


for m_details in manga_details:
    th = m_details.find('th')
    td = m_details.find('td')
    #if th != -1 and th != None:
    #    if len(th.text.strip()) ==0:
    #        continue
    #    else:
    #        print(th.text.strip() + ': ')

    if td != -1 and td != None:
        print(td.text.strip())

    print()
```

And when I get the td text I want to get rid of a specific 'i' html element that gets picked up when running this code. I've been searching on the internet and I found this code: 
https://gist.github.com/braveulysses/120193 
But I'm new to python so I don't really know how to implement this snippet about blacklisting something for my own code.

```
# Remove unwanted tags
    for tag in soup.findAll():
        # Remove blacklisted tags and their contents.
        if tag.name.lower() in tag_blacklist:
            tag.extract()
```

(This code starts at line 43 and ends at 47 in the code I linked)

Comment: you add the tag names you want removed to tag_blacklist. Warning.... the .extract() will remove nested elements when you remove the parent so you may get unwanted results.

Comment: There are i tags in the source html.  I agree with Greg, it would be helpful to see the exact desired output. `manga_details` will be a single node at best so no need for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the expected result, but you can use `td.get_text('^^',strip=True)` to get only the *human-readable* text from the `td` tags.

I used the `^^` to mark where the strings could be sliced, you can also use other values like `|` or `\n`

And if you like you can also use the `.stripped_strings` to perform what ever you like on it `[text for text in td.stripped_strings]`...

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://mangapark.net/manga/tensei-shitara-slime-datta-ken-fuse'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

results = soup.find('section', class_='manga')

print(f"Title: {soup.find('div', class_='pb-1 mb-2 line-b-f hd').find('a').get_text()}")

for row in soup.find('table', class_='attr').find_all('tr'):
    th = row.find('th')
    td = row.find('td')
    
    if len(th.get_text()) != 0:
        print(th.get_text() + ': ', td.get_text('^^',strip=True))
```

**Output**

```
Title: Tensei Shitara Slime Datta Ken Manga
Rating:  Average 9.8 / 10 out of 3841548 total votes.
Popularity:  24th, it has 11.82k monthly views.
Alternative:  О моём перерождении в слизь                                                                   ;                                                                       关于我转生后成为史莱姆的那件事                                                                 ;                                                                       転生したらスライムだった件                                                                   ;                                                                       전생했더니 슬라임이었던 건에 대하여                                                                 ;                                                                       Regarding My Reincarnation as a Slime                                                                   ;                                                                       Regarding Reincarnated to Slime
Author(s):  Fuse
Artist(s):  Kawakami taiki^^;^^Tensei shitara slime datta ken 79
Genre(s):  Shounen^^,^^Action^^,^^Adventure^^,^^Comedy^^,^^Drama^^,^^Fantasy
Type:  Japanese Manga - Read from right to left.
Release:  2015
Status:  Ongoing
Merged By:  #351432^^#354516^^#377050^^#394320
Latest:  ch.78^^ch.77^^ch.076^^ch.75^^ch.74
```

Comment: Cool, it worked, but I don't really understand how what you did didn't pick up the first "tr" that had  what I wanted to ignore.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Concerning your question I also checked if there is a text in the `<th>` like `if len(th.get_text()) != 0:` Think you also tried it with this part of your code `#if th != -1 and th != None:...`